How to use business rule task in Activiti 7 or 8?
I need to use the business rule task in my workflow with Activiti 7. I have tried to use DMN Engine(Decision Table) to implement the business rule task in Activiti 6 but I can't use it in Activiti 7. I have looked for something but I haven't found any relevant issues. Could someone with relevant experience please advise me? I will appreciate your support!
